# Get element.type from generic object in swift

Tags: swift, generics, realm, swift4

I want to write an generic method to read all items from a type in realm and delete them. I wrote this:

```
func deleteAllFromObject<T: Object>(_ object: T) {
    let allUploadingObjects = realm.objects(T.self())

    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(allUploadingObjects)
    }
}
```

but i got an error that says:

> Cannot convert value of type 'T' to expected argument type 'Object.Type'.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe problem in line

```
let allUploadingObjects = realm.objects(T.self())
```

It should be:

```
let allUploadingObjects = realm.objects(T.self) // removed needles parentheses
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate issue is that you need to pass a Metatype to `realm.objects` and not an instance, so you shouldn't put the parentheses behind `T.self`, since the parentheses is the shorthand for `init()`, so instead of passing in the type you're passing in an instance of `T`.

However, you should also change the function signature to `func deleteAllFromObject<T: Object>(_ object: T.Type)`, since you want to be able to call the function with an `Object` type and not an instance of an `Object` subclass.

```
func deleteAllFromObject<T: Object>(_ object: T.Type) {
    let allUploadingObjects = realm.objects(T.self)

    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(allUploadingObjects)
    }
}
```

And then call the function like `deleteAllFromObject(Dog.self)` instead of `deleteAllFromObject(Dog())`.